# C dynamic array inproper figures

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, malloc, memcpy

I would very much appreciate some explanation, why I misuse memcpy i.e. why the output of the following code is inproper:

```
int main()
{
    int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       
    int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    
    memcpy(ptr, array, 5);
    
    printf("%d\n", ptr[0] );
    printf("%d\n", ptr[1] );
    printf("%d\n", ptr[2] );
    printf("%d\n", ptr[3] );
    printf("%d\n", ptr[4] );
    
    free(ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

the output is: 1 2 0 0 0

Comment: These kind of problems can be trivially solved in a few seconds by actually study in advance how a function works before using it, rather than programming through "take a chance" followed by trial & error.

Comment: You are correct in that you have identified the usage of `memcpy` as the culprit.  It needs to be `memcpy(ptr, array, 5*sizeof(int));`//copies all 20 bytes of `array`, not just 5.

Comment: If code needs to make a copy  of  `array`, simplify  allocation to the size of `array`: `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad because you have an array of 5 `int` but you `memcpy` 5 *bytes*. `malloc` and `memcpy` work the same, they expect number of bytes as input. So why do you give one of them `sizeof(int) * 5` and the other `5`?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed this one, little detail.

Comment: @WojciechMierzejewski - You can accept this answer by clicking the hollow checkmark.  That's really the best way to say thanks on this site :)

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd argument of `memcpy()` is number of **bytes** to copy, not number of **elements**.

In this case,

```
memcpy(ptr, array, 5);
```

should be

```
memcpy(ptr, array, sizeof(int) * 5);
```

or

```
memcpy(ptr, array, sizeof(*ptr) * 5);
```

or

```
/* copy the whole array, no *5 in this case */
memcpy(ptr, array, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: UV for the simple `memcpy(ptr, array, sizeof array);`.  Skip that unneeded `5` part.

Answer (score 0):

*why I misuse memcpy i.e. why the output of the following code is inproper*

[memcpy()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) Copies a specified number of bytes from a source buffer to a target buffer.

The statement:

```
int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

Creates a pointer to memory with space for 5 integers, ( i.e. `5*sizeof(int)` )

Likewise, the statement:

```
int array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Creates an `int` `array` with space for `5` `int`. ( again - `5*sizeof(int)` ) But your `memcpy()` statement copies only part of `array`:

```
 memcpy(ptr, array, 5);
```

Illustration:  Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`  the following shows what the portion of `array` that is being  copied:

```
|0001|0002|0003|0004|0005|
|---- -|  first 5 bytes
```

So, only the first 5 bytes of `array`, are copied, while it needs to copy all `5*sizeof(int) == 20` bytes. Change the statement to:

```
memcpy(ptr, array, 5*sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding;

```
memcpy(ptr, array, 5);
```

This copies 5 bytes, where you want to copy 5 integers.  Suggest;

```
memcpy(ptr, array, 5*sizeof(int) );
```